# as3 how can i prevent that a new instance is created by entering a frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, frame, timeline

i am working with several nested movieclip objects in a project. but i get into trouble with the buttons i created and implemented in the nested movieclips:

to describe it in a simple way: 
I have a main movieclip with five frames, including two buttons with listeners to browse between the frames. Then inside of one Frame I have another movieclip with its own buttons. i instanciated it by hand not through code and gave it a specific name like "nestedMc".

Now I dont want to build the Listeners for those buttons inside the class of the nested movieclip class but in its parent class, which works fine until i then goto another frame in the main movieclips timeline and come back.

obviously every time flash enters a frame its contents get created anew (and therefore get new instance names). I could now try solve this through filling the frames via code.

But maybe there is another way to make sure the frame contains the same instance everytime i enter?

Comment: Stop writing code on the timeline. Learn how to use `.as` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeline scripting is a dirty business, and really, a [carry-over compatibility layer for Actionscript 2 projects](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?223798-ActionScript-3-Tip-of-the-Day/page22#post_2098268).  Whenever possible, I highly recommend not doing it, and simply keeping all of your code in your document class. As you're experiencing, timeline code causes headaches.

Consider instead just creating both states of your Stage (it sounds like that's what your two buttons are jumping between) and simply hiding them offstage or setting their alpha to zero and their mouseEnabled state to false.  Furthermore, if the purpose of your frames is to play animation (a tween), consider instead switching to a much more powerful suite such as [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/).  Moving an object over a hundred pixels (smoothly) can be as easy as:

`TweenLite.to(redBall, 3, {x:100});`

Now, if you're manually adding these items to the stage, as long as the object is a dynamic one, you can assign an instance name to it which will be saved between frame loads.  Be aware the object name is not the same as the instanced name.  For example:

```
var redBall:Ball = new Ball();
redBall.name = "bubbles";
```

The object's name is `Ball`, but it's represented as a variable called `redBall`. Its actual [DisplayList](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html) name will likely be ambiguous (such as "Instance71"), and I can manually define it as `"bubbles"`.  3 different names for the same object, all very different and necessary.

Even if you give the object a displayList name, you may not be able to reference it through code unless you enable Automatically declare stage instances, which basically creates on each object a pointer to the displayList object.

[image: As seen in your project settings]

That said, you can always fetch the object by other means.  Obviously, your buttons are always appearing, but you're trying to find a very specific object on the stage.  At this point, we can use [getChildByName()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29) or [getChildAt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildAt%28%29).

Hope that helps.
-Cheers

Comment: thank you. i am not writing code into the timeline (didnt know that this is still possible). the problem derived from my missing understanding for the differences between name-property and instance name. thank you a lot for pointing that out!